# Heap Dump Analysis needs your Attention

Tags: weblogic, heap-memory

I have a weblogic server that throws OOM error when it starts. Because of which my application is not behaving properly.

I have collected Heap dump [Snap Shot below], however, I am not good at understanding the output.

[Image Snap: http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7470/heapanalysis.jpg](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7470/heapanalysis.jpg)

Can you please help understand why am i getting the OOM errors ?
 Below are the JVM arguments.

```
 Starting WLS with line:
 /java -server   -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -Xnoclassgc -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -verbose:gc -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Below is the errors seen in the logs.

```
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Dumping heap to
> java_pid16660.hprof ...
> 115.814: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 743854K(1048576K)] 743854K(1507328K), 0.0050472 secs]
> 115.819: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start] Heap dump file created [778142756 bytes in 3.935 secs] <Jan 20, 2013 10:56:05 PM PST> <Critical>
> <WorkManager> <BEA-002911> <WorkManager weblogic.kernel.System failed
> to schedule a request due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap 
> space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> > <Jan 20, 2013 10:56:05 PM PST> <Critical> <WorkManager> <BEA-002911> <WorkManager weblogic.kernel.System failed to schedule a request due
> to java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExcept ion: 26214404
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26214404
>         at weblogic.work.CalendarQueue.add(CalendarQueue.java:39)
>         at weblogic.work.RequestManager.addToPriorityQueue(RequestManager.java:263)
>         at weblogic.work.RequestManager.executeIt(RequestManager.java:235)
>         at weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl.schedule(ServerWorkManagerImpl.java:142)
>         at weblogic.corba.cos.transactions.RecoveryRegistrar.run(RecoveryRegistrar.java:47)
>         Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Run your HPROF Heap Dump through the `Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool` - and look for the `"Leak Suspect"` Report - usually the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you download [Visual VM](http://visualvm.java.net/), install all the plugins, and attach it to the PID when you run WebLogic.

Your HPROF is hard to read, but if those are bytes I don't see a problem here.

Comment: I do not have access to do anything on the JVM, All i can get is the Heap dump whichever way you want to see it. I have attached the error, please let me know if that helped ?

Comment: Get somebody who does have access to the server to install it and run for you.  Nope, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

As I am more familiar with the Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool, I will answer on how to analyze the HPROF file through the Eclipse MAT tool.

Once you open the HPROF file in eclipse and finish parsing, if the cause is simpler or more obvious (to MAT)  it will point to the culprit thread / web-request in the " Leak Suspects report ".

If you are not so lucky then  do this:

1. Click on Histogram option
2. Sort table based on Retained Heap field on the right
3. Histogram view shows a table of active objects with memory consumed, usually low level
       classes like HashMaps, Lists etc.
4. your aim is to find classes up the tree from these top consumer, upto the class(es) 
       which you recognize are part of your application code and so are the initiators of
       the memory hogs. If its a web-app you might get to the specific user HTTP request 
       that started it all.
5. Pick the top Class Name and right click select "Shortest Path to GC Roots - >  exclude 
       phantom, soft , weak references".
6. The resulting table lists the top level Java Class or Http Request which started the 
       thread responsible for the memory outage. This list gives you narrower field from 
       which you can analyze what is causing it to misbehave.

**Note:**  MAT is pretty memory intensive itself, so for parsing a HPROF file of size b/w 5-8 GB, you will need atleast 8 GB RAM and also set initialization parameters of MAT tool through the file : **MemoryAnalyzer.ini**   specifically  Xmx param , say to  -Xmx6144m